# How to download a webpage's all images at once?

Tags: mac, safari

For example, I love military decorations, and here's Wikipedia's [Service Ribbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Ribbon), how can I download all the ribbon images at once instead of clicking them one by one and then select "Save image as"?

Comment: It would be much quicked for you to google it. For example http://www.wikihow.com/Download-All-Images-on-a-Web-Page-at-Once

Comment: @Jaqenhghar That's for windows, does it work on Mac?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Automator

Use OS X's **Automator.app** to find, extract, and save the images from your current web page. The combination of Actions needed are:

- Get Current Webpage from Safari
- Get Contents of Webpages
- Save Images From Web Content

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac).

[image: Automator]

### Terminal

An alternative approach is to use `curl` through the command line, [What's the fastest and easiest way to download all the images from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812562/whats-the-fastest-and-easiest-way-to-download-all-the-images-from-a-website).

Comment: Still relevant in macOS Big Sur. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Using `wget`:

```
wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Ribbon -p -A .jpg,.jpeg,.png -H -nd
```

`-p` (`--page-requisites`) downloads resources like images and stylesheets even when you don't use `-r`. `-A` specifies suffixes or glob-style patterns to accept. `-H` (`--span-hosts`) follows links to other domains like `upload.wikimedia.org`. `-nd` (`--no-directories`) downloads all files to the current directory without creating subdirectories.

You can install `wget` with `brew install wget` after installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

You might also just use `curl`:

```
curl example.tumblr.com | grep -o 'src="[^"]*.jpg"' | cut -d\" -f2 | 
        while read l; do curl "$l" -o "${l##*/}"; done
```

Downloading images from Tumblr or Blogspot:

```
api="http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/example.tumblr.com/posts?type=photo&api_key=get from tumblr.com/api"
seq 0 20 $(curl -s $api | jq .response.total_posts) |
    while read n; do
        curl -s "$api&offset=$n" |
            jq -r '.response.posts[].photos[].original_size.url'
    done | awk '!a[$0]++' | parallel wget -q

curl -L 'http://someblog.blogspot.com/atom.xml?max-results=499' |
    grep -io 'href=&quot;http://[^&]*.jpg' | 
    cut -d\; -f2 |
    awk '!a[$0]++' |
    parallel wget -q
```

Comment: Where do you get `parallel` from?

Comment: You can install `parallel` and `jq` with `brew install parallel jq` after installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or with `sudo port install parallel jq` after installing [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php).

Answer (score 5):

Using Firefox (tested with v. 61), without additional software:

1. Find the media tab of the Page Info window. This can be found through one of the following manners:

   - Context menu > View Page Info > Media
   - Context menu for image > View Image Info
2. Select all image addresses.
3. Click Save As... and select the folder to download all images to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox and Flashgot, which is an extension which does pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

You can find Flashgot on the official Mozilla addons website [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/flashgot/)

Flashgot uses a download manager of your choice, either the one integrated in Firefox, curl, wget, or others. Personally I like [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/downthemall/).

Comment: Hi welcome to AskDifferent, I find if a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting.  Also some instructions and a link may get you more upvotes. Please take the time to read the Answer and Question section of the [help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) page.

Comment: @Deesbek expanded answer :)